# Typescript: Types of property 'constructor' are incompatible

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm new in Typescript and I'm trying to migrate a JS customized library to TS by adding all types. 
This is an easy example of what I am try to do.
Original JS File (Class) 'parser.js':

```
class Parser {
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
} 
module.exports = Parser;
```

Types file 'parsertypes.d.ts':

```
export type tbrat = {
  constructor(name:string): tbrat;
};
```

TS utilizing file 'utilize.ts':

```
import Parser from './parser';
import {tbrat} from './parsertypes';
const n: tbrat = new Parser('hello');
```

ERROR:

```
Type 'Parser' is not assignable to type 'tbrat'. Types of property 'constructor' are incompatible. Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(name: string) => tbrat'. Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(name: string): tbrat'.
```

I don't understand what I am missing. I can't move the original JS file to TS for particular reasons.

Comment: `constructor(name)`  That's the same as doing `constructor(name:any)`  So `any` <> `string`..

Comment: There are no constructors for types only for classes

Comment: What are you trying to describe with the `tbrat` type?  Right now it reads "a value of type `tbrat` has a `constructor` property which is a function that takes a `string` and produces a `tbrat`."  That doesn't match a `Parser` object for a few reasons; one is that a newable function isn't the same as a regular function, and the other is that the `constructor` property of a class instance [isn't very strongly typed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) in TypeScript.  You could fix both of these issues, but I don't understand why you need this.

Answer (score 4):

The same way that JavaScript has modules, TypeScript does, too.

If you were writing pure TypeScript, you would not need to do the following, as the transpiler would take care of this for you. However, as you are creating a definition file, you need to declare a module in the same way that your JavaScript code does.

You need to declare your parser module in `parser.d.ts`:

```
declare module "parser" {
  class Parser {
    constructor(name:string): void
  }

  export default Parser;
}
```

You then import `parser` as you normally would in `utilize.ts`:

```
import Parser from 'parser'

const foo = new Parser('test')
```

Further reading: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: Thanks apsillers, hopefully it is helpful. Will keep this in mind for future answers!

Comment: Ive tryed to keep my JS as I need and modify the parser.d.ts but it is not allowed to use void in enviroment context. So it fails. And also it fails in the usage because semms I can't use 'new' without a constructor signature.

Comment: codepen.io/nowy5/project/editor/DBjPVx Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but It gives me this error "Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature."

Comment: Get It. when i use it i have to call it in this way: const foo = new Parser.Parser('test'). Thanks for the help

Comment: The solution @nowy doesn't work. It's ok in ts but when i create the relative js it can't find the module parser

Answer (score 1):

There are no constructors for `type` definitions only for classes, so you might want to use `declare`, something like the following will work:

```
class Parser {
  constructor(name){
    name;
  }
} 

declare class tbrat {
    constructor(name: string) {

    }
}

const n: tbrat = new Parser('hello');
```

Please also take a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51139402/4952551) from Noel Varanda.